# Callback URL for Live Objects?

Tags: rest, api, callback, iot, orange-api

I develop an application that uses Live Objects REST API to collect my devices data. Would it be possible to configure a callback URL on Live Objects in order to get notifications or should i poll Live Object regularly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot define a callback URL in Live Objects, but you have other solutions depending on your needs. To consume data in real time you should use Live Objects MQTT interface instead of polling with API REST. If your need is more to be notified of particular events or conditions on data (for example temperature higher than xxx degrees), you can use the Live Object Event  Processing feature, also available through MQTT interface. See Live Objects manual for more details

Comment: Ok thank you a lot. I found it [https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/doc/html/lo_manual.html](https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/doc/html/lo_manual.html)